# Не могу сделать так чтобы выполнялся 2ой и 3ий пример

Tags: java

> Описание На этом этапе вы должны проанализировать поле
> крестики-нолики.
>
> Примечание. На этом этапе либо "Х", либо " о " может начать игру.
>
> После печати поля вам нужно найти то состояние, в котором находится
> игра в данный момент. Возможное состояние:
>
> "Игра не закончена" - когда ни у одной стороны нет тройки подряд, но
> на поле есть пустые клетки; "Ничья" - когда ни одна сторона не имеет
> тройки в ряд и на поле нет пустых ячеек; "X выигрывает" - когда на
> поле есть три X подряд; "О выигрыше" - когда на поле есть три часа
> подряд; "Невозможно" - когда на поле есть три X подряд, а также три O
> подряд. Или поле имеет намного больше X, чем O, или наоборот (если
> разница равна 2 или более, должно быть 1 или 0). Кроме того, вы можете
> использовать '' или '_' для печати пустых ячеек - это зависит от вас.
>
> Примеры В приведенных ниже примерах показаны выходные данные для
> некоторых предопределенных состояний. Ваша программа должна работать
> точно так же.

> Пример 1:

```
Enter cells: XXXOO__O_
---------
| X X X |
| O O _ |
| _ O _ |
---------
X wins
```

> Example 2:

```
Enter cells: XOXOXOXXO
---------
| X O X |
| O X O |
| X X O |
---------
X wins
```

> Example 3:

```
Enter cells: XOOOXOXXO
---------
| X O O |
| O X O |
| X X O |
---------
O wins
```

> Example 4:

```
Enter cells: XOXOOXXXO
---------
| X O X |
| O O X |
| X X O |
---------
Draw
```

> Example 5:

```
Enter cells: XO_OOX_X_
---------
| X O   |
| O O X |
|   X   |
---------
Game not finished
```

> Example 6:

```
Enter cells: XO_XO_XOX
---------
| X O _ |
| X O _ |
| X O X |
---------
Impossible
```

> Example 7:

```
Enter cells: _O_X__X_X
---------
|   O   |
| X     |
| X   X |
---------
Impossible
```

> Example 8:

```
Enter cells: _OOOO_X_X
---------
|   O O |
| O O   |
| X   X |
---------
Impossible
```

> Код

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();

        char[] array = str.toCharArray();
        char[][] array2 = new char[3][3];

        int countOfX = (int) str.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 'X').count();
        int countOfO = (int) str.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 'O').count();
        int countOfFreeSpace = (int) str.chars().filter(ch -> ch == '_').count();

        System.out.println(countOfX);
        System.out.println(countOfO);
        System.out.println(countOfFreeSpace);

        int m = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                array2[i][j] = array[m];
                m++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println("| " + array[0] + " " + array[1] + " " + array[2] + " |");
        System.out.println("| " + array[3] + " " + array[4] + " " + array[5] + " |");
        System.out.println("| " + array[6] + " " + array[7] + " " + array[8] + " |");
        System.out.println("---------");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            int numOfXToWin = 0;
            int numOfOToWin = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if ((int) array2[i][j] == 88) {
                    numOfXToWin += array2[i][j];
                } else if ((int) array2[i][j] == 79) {
                    numOfOToWin += array2[i][j];
                }

                if (numOfXToWin == 264) {
                    System.out.println("X wins");
                    return;
                } else if (numOfOToWin == 237) {
                    System.out.println("O wins");
                    return;
                } else if (countOfO == countOfFreeSpace && countOfX == countOfFreeSpace) {
                    System.out.println("Game not finished");
                    return;
                }
                else if (countOfO + countOfX == 9) {
                    System.out.println("Draw");
                    return;
                } else if (Math.abs(countOfX - countOfO) > 1) {
                    System.out.println("Impossible");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас проверка только горизонталей. Нужно добавит проверку вертикалей и диагоналей

Comment: Вот я и не могу понять как это записать.Так же во втором цикле добавив еще пару If-ов или как то еще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проверка только горизонталей. Нужно добавить проверку вертикалей и диагоналей

```
int getAddend(char ch) {
  switch (ch) {
    case 'X': return 1;
    case 'O': return -1;
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}

..............

if (Math.abs(countOfX - countOfO) > 1) {
  System.out.println("Impossible");
  return;
}
boolean xWin = false;
boolean oWin = false;
int dataMainD = 0;
int dataSecD = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  int dataRow = 0;
  int dataCol = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    dataRow += getAddend(array2[i][j]);
    dataCol += getAddend(array2[j][i]);
  }
  if (dataRow == 3 || dataCol == 3)
    xWin = true;
  if (dataRow == -3 || dataCol == -3)
    oWin = true;
  dataMainD += getAddend(array2[i][i]);
  dataSecD += getAddend(array2[i][2 - i]);
}
if (dataMainD == 3 || dataSecD == 3)
  xWin = true;
if (dataMainD == -3 || dataSecD == -3)
  oWin = true;

if (xWin && oWin)
  System.out.println("Impossible");
else if (xWin)
  System.out.println("X wins");
else if (oWin)
  System.out.println("O wins");
else if (countOfFreeSpace > 0)
  System.out.println("Not Finished");
else
  System.out.println("Draw");
```

Comment: При вводе таких данных происходит ничья "XOOOXOXXO" , хотя тут должны выйграть O.

Comment: @fastrapier1 Исправил

Comment: Странно,так же не проходит с таким инпутом:"XOOOXOXXO".Все та же ничья.

Comment: @fastrapier1 а у меня работает. Если вы не можете тупо скопировать код, то я ничем помочь не могу

Comment: Спасибо большое все получилось!